# Cannot pass data from view to controller when list is big

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

aspI have functions to view/remove data:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["table1"] = _repository.GetAll("table1").ToList();
        ViewData["table2"] = _repository.GetAll("table2").ToList();
        return View("Index");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Remove(string fromTable, List<Items> items)
    {
        try
        {
            var itemsToDelete = items.Where(x => x.Checked).ToList();
            _repository.Remove(itemsToDelete, fromTable);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

html:

```html
@{
    const string changeQueueTable = "table1";
    const string changeQueueErrorsTable = "table2";
    var table1 = (List<Items>)ViewData["table1"];
    var table2 = (List<Items>)ViewData["table2"];
    var error = (string)ViewData["error"];
}
@if (error != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger mt-3" role="alert">@error</div>
}
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="border-right: 1px solid #dee2e6">
        @if (changeQueue != null)
        {
            var id = 0;
            <h3>Change queue table</h3>
            <form asp-controller="ErrorConsumer" asp-action="" method="post">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Object Id</th>
                    <th>Object type</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @if (table1.Count > 0)
                {
                    @for (var i = 0; i < table1.Count; i++)
                    {
                        <input type="hidden" name="@("items[" + i + "].ObjectId")" value="@table1[i].ObjectId"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="@("items[" + i + "].ObjectType")" value="@table1[i].ObjectType"/>
                        <tr>
                            <td>@(++id)</td>
                            <td>
                                <input name="@("items[" + i + "].Checked")" type="checkbox" value="true" @(table1[i].Checked ? "checked" : " ")/>
                            </td>
                            <td>@table1[i].ObjectId</td>
                            <td>@table1[i].ObjectType</td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="8" style="text-align: center;">No items found</td>
                    </tr>
                }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="row justify-content-end" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <input type="hidden" name="fromTable" value="@changeQueueTable"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="toTable" value="@changeQueueErrorsTable"/>
                    <div style="float: right">
                        <button style="width: 84px; margin-right: -30px; @(table1.Count == 0 ? "display:none" : "display:block")" class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="Move" title="Move" type="submit">Move</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <div style="margin-left: -10px; float: right">
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary" style="@(table1.Count == 0 ? "display:none" : "display:block")" asp-action="Remove" title="Remove " type="submit">Remove</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        }

    </div>
</div>
```

This worked correctly, but now I noticed that when the list is bigger (+500 items in a list) my remove method gets null values (here: I`ActionResult Remove(string fromTable, List<ChangeQueueItem> items)` ). What could be wrong here? Why it works correctly with 10 items in a list, but does not pass values when list is bigger?

Comment: The `ViewData` and `ViewBag` objects that hold the extra pieces of information that you want to send to your `View` like user logged in details etc.  However for more complex data, like in your case, have you considered using a `ViewModel` to hold your data?

Comment: @RahulSharma so `VIewData` won't work with larger datasets?

Comment: It is not like that since I have personally used `Session` to hold large amounts of data in my projects. Have you tried using `Session` instead of `ViewData` or `ViewBag` in your case? I prefer to use a `ViewModel` if I have large data but if `Session` is the only way, then you can try that.

Comment: @RahulSharma I'd like to keep it as is with ViewData if I can make it work

Comment: Ok. How have you configured your `Session` state in your configuration settings? Maybe that could be a problem

Comment: Solved by adding:

` services.Configure<FormOptions>(options => { options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue; });
        services.AddMvc(options => { options.MaxModelBindingCollectionSize = int.MaxValue; });`

Comment: Ok, I have updated tags in your question also for .Net-Core